# JOIN on a Table Valued Parameter - Sql Server T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a stored procedure that accepts a table valued parameter. I would like to do a join with that table only if it has values.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.TestProc
    (@name UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = null,
     @hasCityGuids bit, 
     @cityGuids dbo.GUIDTableType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT x1 , x2
   FROM Address A
   WHERE (@hasCityGuids = 0 
          OR A.CityGuid IN (SELECT Value FROM @cityGuids)) 
END
```

The other option is to do an outer join

```
SELECT 
    x1 , x2
FROM 
    Address A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    @cityGuids CG ON A.CityGuid = CG.Value
```

Is there a faster option than these 2 ? I have a complex query and I had to use this filter on multiple places, which is slowing down the query.

Comment: What do you mean that you would like to do a join with that table only if it has values. You are better off just joining to it rather than checking for values first. You would be performing a needless check. By checking for values you are already accessing the table. You may as well go ahead and perform your join or subquery with the table in that case. Maybe there is a different approach you can take. What is it that you are intending to do? What is your goal or final objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's like an issue I've had in the past, it's slow because of the OR here and the optimizer wasn't behaving and using indexes

```
WHERE (@hasCityGuids = 0 OR A.CityGuid IN (
          Select Value from  @cityGuids ))
```

Instead, we ended up with an actual IF statement, something like

```
CREATE PROC dbo.TestProc( @name UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = null,
                          @hasCityGuids bit, 
                          @cityGuids dbo.GUIDTableType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN

   IF @hasCityGuids = 0 THEN
   BEGIN
   SELECT x1 , x2
   FROM Address A
   END
   ELSE
   SELECT x1 , x2
   FROM Address A INNER join @cityGuids CG ON A.CityGuid = CG.Value

END
```

Comment: The issue is my query is not simple like this, it has around 10 select subqueries as columns, and i have to apply this filter on most of these subqueries. Not sure i can use an IF statement here.

Comment: Why not?   If the TVP has rows, you execute one complex query, if not you execute a different one.   Then the optimizer can choose the best plan for the query that gets executed.

Comment: Okay thanks will try. I didn't want to duplicate almost same logic twice,with just the difference in Outer Join logic. But i guess that is the way to go in SQL.

Comment: Well, it's worth noting that the difference for us was the INNER join. It was then able to use indexes, which made it faster. I don't know if an OUTER would have the same benefits. It may depend on your DB and keys/indexes.

Comment: Oh, your other option, if you have a bunch of these filters, is to create dynamic sql. You do have to take care with the security of such things, but dynamically creating the sql then executing it with exec_sql might really help performance. It might also tank it, though, so you'd have to just try it and see how it goes. Hard to say it would be great without knowing more about your DB

Answer (score 0):

You can try an exists

```
BEGIN
   SELECT x1 , x2
   FROM Address A
   WHERE (@hasCityGuids = 0 
          OR EXISTS ( SELECT null FROM @cityGuids innerHolder where innerHolder.Value = A.CityGuid) 
END
```

You can try putting the TVP values into a #temp table and create an index on it after its hydrated

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end


CREATE TABLE #Holder
(ID INT )


/* simulate your insert */
INSERT INTO #HOLDER (ID) 
select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
/* 
select value from FROM @cityGuids 
*/


/* CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_TempHolder_ID ON #Holder (ID) */

CREATE INDEX IDX_TempHolder_ID ON #Holder (ID)




/* then try exists */

       SELECT x1 , x2
       FROM Address A
       WHERE (@hasCityGuids = 0 
              OR EXISTS ( SELECT null FROM #Holder innerHolder where innerHolder.Value = A.CityGuid) 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end
```