# Many values for the phone field in one WHERE using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, sql-server

What is the best way to process a list of phone numbers in the where condition? Use a simple loop? Or is it possible to modify the Sql query for MS SQL Server somehow?

```
string sqlExpression = @'select d.* from MobilePhone m
    join User u on m.User_IDREF = u.User_ID
    join Device d on u.User_ID = d.User_ID
    WHERE m.MonilePhone = @MobilePhone;' // I want to insert a list '+7897654321' AND '+7878765444' AND so on...

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();

    SQLCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);

    command.Parameters.Add("@MobilePhone", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters["@MobilePhone"].Value = ''; // I want to insert a list '+7897654321' AND '+7878765444' AND so on... Maybe to use a loop for this?
    
    SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
}
```

Comment: You could pass an XML parameter containing your "list", or use a table value parameter: [how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code), newer versions of sql-server can use  json as well, so those are some options.

Comment: You can use table values parameter and use `IN` clause.

Comment: In addition to passing a list of values as XML or a TVP, you can use a comma-separated list and parse with `STRING_SPLIT` or as a JSON array and parse with `OPENSJON`, depending on your SQL Server version.

Comment: Slight detour....I would highly recommend you wrap your connection and command objects (and anything else using the iDisposable interface) in a USING statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: @Chetan
If I use IN together with parameters, then there will be no restrictions on creating parameters in the loop?

Comment: @Timur If you follow the suggestions given, you won't need a loop. SQL uses a set based approach, and loops should generally be unnecessary.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson Thanks. There is a question... Does your example fit the WHERE condition? It looks like it only works for INSERT

Comment: @Timur you would join your parameter, be it xml, json or table value, on the appropriate table in your query and your where clause wouldn't be necessary. Here's some links to help: [join-on-a-table-valued-parameter-sql-server-t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819807/join-on-a-table-valued-parameter-sql-server-t-sql), [join-on-data-from-xml-in-t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498300/join-on-data-from-xml-in-t-sql), and...

Comment: [how-to-join-json-list-with-a-table-in-sql-server-using-openjson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424402/how-to-join-json-list-with-a-table-in-sql-server-using-openjson)

Comment: You can also derive a table from a list of strings in SQL like this: `(values ('+7897654321'), ('+7897654321')) PhoneList(InputPhone)`. So your sql would be: `select d.* from MobilePhone m
    join User u on m.User_IDREF = u.User_ID
    join Device d on u.User_ID = d.User_ID
 join (values ('+7897654321'), ('+7897654321')) PhoneList(InputPhone) on PhoneList.InputPhone = m.MobilePhone`